# c# go to specific line in text file then skip a few lines and edit

Tags: c#, text

I know how to read through all lines of a file and replace a selected line when a certain sequence of characters is found. The issue that I'm having at the moment is that I'm stuck with a structure that has no unique string to search for except for the main class name. So for example I'd know that the name of the class is "List_of_boats" and the structure tells me that 11 lines underneath that line is the value "items=2;" which I need to change to a certain value, depending on the amount of items I want to insert there.

Is there a way to use the foreach function or something to do this? I have provided some code that I've already got so far but I'm kind of stuck now.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileToMerge);
var linID = 0;
foreach (var line in lines) {
    if (line.Contains("ace_arsenal_saved_loadouts")) {
        var newlinID = linID + 11; //go from ace_arsenal_saved_loadouts to "items=x;" to change number of items.
    }
    linID = linID + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the enumerable to an array, and loop through it by index:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileToMerge).ToArray();
for (var linID = 0; linID < lines.Length; linID++) {
    var line = lines[linID];
    if (line.Contains("ace_arsenal_saved_loadouts")) {
        var newlinID = linID + 11; //go from ace_arsenal_saved_loadouts to "items=x;" to change number of items.
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid now. I didn't think of this option! thanks a lot <3